# How to remove multiple strings of numbers from a list and return it vertically as usable ints

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, vertical-alignment

I'm working on a function that takes a list of strings of numbers as an argument. I need to extract the strings from the list as individual strings, not a single string, like in string = " " string.join(list), where the outcome is a single index. I also need to split the strings and arrange them vertically.

pass as arg-- `["1 + 2", "1 - 2"]`

remove strings from list-- `"1 + 2", "1 - 2"`

return strings vertically--

```
" "

1 1

+ - 

2 2

" "
```

I tried the following

```
def list_To_String(list):

#I am trying to print each string vertically

    test_list = ["1 + 2", "2 - 3"]

    for item in range(len(test_list)):
        for x in test_list:
            print(x[item])
print(list_To_String(test_list))
```

my code prints out the first item in each index, and that's not what I want. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide expected input and output?

Comment: @Vinay Emmaadii both are included in the question.

Comment: @BhavinT both are included in the question

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip()`:

```
def list_to_string(_list: list):
    for x, y in zip(*_list):
        print(x, y)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    list_to_string(["1 + 2", "2 - 3"])
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#zip):

> Make an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterables. Returns an iterator of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables.

EDIT (19/Nov):
As @BhavinT correctly pointed, this will not work with lists with more than 2 elements. Please see this snippet instead:

```
def list_to_string(_list: list):
    for values in zip(*_list):
        print(*values)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    list_to_string(["1 + 2", "2 - 3", "4 x 4"])
```

Comment: why include an if __name__ == "__main__" script? Isn't that exclusively for importing modules and deciding which chunks of code to run?